# Compute conditional probability using fewest for_loop, Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, for-loop, performance

I guess there must be an algorithm that does my problem most efficiently but I haven't found it. My problem is to compute a discrete distribution for A, Prob(A). Using conditional Probability, we know:
Prob(A)=Prob(A|B,C,D)*Prob(B|C,D)*Prob(C|D)*Prob(D)
A,B,C,D are dependent and I only know the expressions for each term above.
So in my code, I used 4 layers of for loop:

```
    Solution=zeros(1,max_A)  % store Prob(A=0,1,2,3,...max_A) in each cell.
    for a =0 to max_A
        for b=0 to max_B
            for c=0 to max_C
                for d=0 to max_D
                Result= Prob(A=a|B=b,C=c,D=d)*Prob(B|C,D)*Prob(C|D)*Prob(D)
                Solution(a)= Solution(a)+Result % sum up the result 
                                                %in each iteration
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

In the real program I am dealing with Prob(A|B,C,D), Prob(B|C,D), Prob(C|D), Prob(D), each invokes a 21 layers of For Loop. It is terribly inefficient and slow. Matlab choked on my code and it has been 5 days that it run.

Really appreciate any idea or demo codes that help me eliminate some of the loops.

Many Thanks!
Ester

Answer (score 1):

I think it is that slow because you are unnecessarily repeating computations. If you store the partial results it should be faster. I can't really try this because your code is not a complete running example, but how about something like this:

```
for c = 0 to max_C
    pC(c) = 0;
    for d = 0 to max_D
        pC(c) = pC(c) + Prob(C|D) * Prob(D);
    end
end
for b = 0 to max_B
    pB(b) = 0;
    for c = 0 to max_C
        pB(b) = pB(b) + Prob(B|C) * pC(c);
    end
end
for a = 0 to max_A
    pA(a) = 0;
    for b = 0 to max_B
        pA(a) = pA(a) + Prob(A|B) * pB(b);
    end
end
Solution = sum(a)
```

Here `pC`, `pB`, and `pA` are arrays to store the intermediate results.

It should be possible to make this even more efficient by preallocation and vectorization, especially if the Prob() functions take and return vector arguments, but I think this is the most important step to make your algorithm finish in a reasonable time.

Btw., the end result `Solution` is probably not that interesting because it should be 1, because it is the sum over the probabilities of an exhaustive set of possibilities – right?